# Usage of "but" as preposition

Tags: verbs, prepositions, infinitives

About usage of "but", I am confused with this sentence:

> You have no choice but to perform the back-test yourself.

"But" is the preposition in this sentence. Why is the use of infinitive? Can I change the verb (perform) to *-ing* form (gerund) as follows?

> You have no choice but performing the back-test yourself.

Comment: This is the 'except (for); if not for' sense of _but_, as found in [_Nobbut_-Clefts](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf) like _But for him, we would have won_, or  _There's nothing but gingerbread left._

Answer (score 1):

The word that determines the form of *perform* is *choice* not *but*. You have the choice **to do** something, not **doing** it. So it has to be:

> You have no choice *to perform* the test yourself.

You cannot say:

> You have no choice *performing* the test yourself.

You can use a gerund, however, if *choice* is followed by *in*:

> You have no choice in performing the test.

This aspect of language has been termed "*grammatical collocation*". Here is part of the entry on this term in the Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar (p70):

> **Grammatical collocation**: a construction where a verb, adjective, etc.
>   must be followed by a particular preposition, or a noun must be
>   followed by a particular form of the verb (e.g. account for; afraid
>   of; the foresight to do it (not *of doing it).

Comment: But I thought the question was about *but*. If that's not so then this is a comment, right?

Comment: ? *You have no choice to perform the test* is unidiomatic at best: *you have no choice but to perform the test* (as asked) is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Well the two questions in the question text are _Why is the use of infinitive? Can I change the verb (perform) to -ing form (gerund) as follows?_, which I have answered. In any case, it was too long for a comment